# How to display images with different mimes types

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to display images through a loop. I can only display one file type like .jpg. I would like to display two or three file types.

Any ideas on how to do it will be good thanks

```
@foreach($data as $row)
                    <?php //This code is to display the products next to each other so it looks great

                        $count++;

                        if ($count == 6 ) 
                            {
                                $count = 0;
                                echo '</div>';
                                echo '<br/>';
                                echo '<div class="row">';
                                echo '<div class="col-md-2">';
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                echo '<div class="col-md-2">';
                            }
                        ?>
                            <img class="img-rounded" height="140" width="140" src="/images/catalog/{{$row->sku}}.jpg">

                            <br/>

                            <a href="/product/view/{{$row->id}}">{{$row->name}}</a>

                            <br/>
                            <br/>

                            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/product/view/{{$row->id}}">View</a>
                        </div>
            @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the hardcoded .jpg

```
<img class="img-rounded" height="140" width="140" src="/images/catalog/{{$row->sku}}">
```

Comment: what other data is in the $row object? is there something in there that could be used to determine the correct file extension to add?

Comment: User can upload at this stage only jpeg images. I want the user to be able to upload more types. The $row var holds the filename but not the type

Answer (score 0):

You have to save uploaded image file name with mimes type (eg. image1.jpg, image2.jpg) in image table. So you can use that file name instant of sku.

Comment: I can do that but then its exstra data in the database. Is there no html code that might solve this